# scrlttr2 - Change Fontstyle for the whole document

Tags: fonts, scrlttr2

I want to write a letter that uses the same Font(style) as my CV.

For the CV i am using the europecv-class - so the font is on default: helvetica, narrow (condensed helvetica)

How can i achieve the same font in my letter?

If i use the following snippet, i get helvetica:

```
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{helvet}
```

but how can i get a condensed font, like in my CV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the series to the condensed variant.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\seriesdefault}{mc}
\renewcommand*{\bfdefault}{bc}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \textbf{lorem ipsum}

\end{document}
```

Here a comparison of the two versions (standard above, condensed below):

[image]

Alternatively (and IMO preferably), you could use `tgheros` (an Helvetica clone but with full `TS1` support) with the `condensed` option

```
\usepackage[condensed]{tgheros}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does this only apply to articles? It seems like it doesn't do anything, at least when i'm using scrlttr2

Comment: @WoulterM It works for me also with `scrlttr2`. If you have a problem please post a MWE which reproduces the issue.

Comment: i put the code in the wrong place. it worked pretty good! thanks!